# Bootstrap modal reset to initial content

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap modal.

I want to make it like a wizard.

```
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking on the Next button, the Content 1 will hide and the next content will show up.

That is working fine. Here's the js:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
  $('#myModal .modal-body').html('<p>Content 2</p>');
});
```

Now if I close the modal, and re-open back the modal. It is displaying the Content 2 instead of showing the Content 1 as the intial content.

How do I make the modal to display the Content 1 as the initial content whenever I open the modal? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/B9p6D/1/)

simple function on Next button click event

```
function hideContent()
{
    $("#ctn1").hide();
    $("#ctn2").show();
}
```

**Modal Window**

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#newModal1">Launch</a>

<div id="newModal1" class="modal hide fade">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p id="ctn1">Content 1</p>

      <p style="display:none;" id="ctn2">Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">

      <button id="next" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick=" hideContent()">Next</button>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" data-value="0">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well it works perfectly, but after clicking the next button. If you click on cancel button and then click the launch link again, the modal will end up showing the content 2 instead of showing the content 1 as intial display

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/B9p6D/2/ simple trick can work for it..i had removed data-dismiss="modal" from Cancle Button and add class for hide Modal..

Comment: There's one issue. What happens when user don't click close but instead click anywhere else in the page. Modal will still dismiss, but Content change will not occur

Comment: change in div of ur modal <div id="newModal1" class="modal hide fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">  demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/B9p6D/3/

Answer (score 0):

The following command will permanently replace the modal content

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').html('<p>Content 2</p>');
```

If you want to get `Content 1` back again, invoke following code from JavaScript to open the modal.

```
$('#myModal .modal-body').html('<p>Content 1</p>');
$('#myModal').modal("show");
```

Although I suggest have all content available in different sections by default and rather than changing the content, use show/hide of sections.

Fiddle with you existing code (Replacing of content)
http://jsfiddle.net/TpjWD/2/

Fiddle with hiding of code 
http://jsfiddle.net/TpjWD/3/

Comment: where to put the `$('#myModal .modal-body').modal("show");` ?
Is it inside the `$('#next').click(function(){   });`

Comment: It'll not be inside the $("#next"), but when you invoke the modal. You may have anchor that toggles the modal. Instead give this function on click of it